# X-ray + browserstack we want to integrate X-ray with browserstack

Tags: browserstack, x-ray

The testcases which we want to automate are present in X-ray and the webdriver.io franework in which the automated testcases are present is running on browser stack. So is there any integration present for this? that we create a testplan in X-ray and trigger the execution of testcases from X-ray on browser stack?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out!

webdriver.io tests can be run using configuration file with command.
`wdio wdio.conf.js`

In order to run on browserstack we needs to use browserstack   services,BROWSERSTACK_USER and BROWSERSTACK_KEY in `wdio.conf.js` file.

`services: ['browserstack'],                                                                   user:BROWSERSTACK_USER,                                                                             key:BROWSERSTACK_KEY`

With updating this configuration and adding the right browser Capabilities tests can be run on browserstack

Comment: Hi Vaibhav thanks for reply but i want to know how can we trigger browserstack run from x-ray. Any integration between X-ray and browser stack available?